# Grouping Multiple Counts on Pivot Table by Year

Tags: sql-server

I have just started learning SQL. I've written the following:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom Date = '01-Jan-2014', @DateTo Date = '31-Dec-2014'

SELECT TotalCalls, UniqueCalls, TotalEmails, UniqueEmails, AgentsContacted, Instructed FROM 

(   SELECT *, 

(SELECT YEAR(EventDate)) AS year,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Events JOIN dbo.ContactType 
                    ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID 
                    WHERE ContactTypeName = 'Call' AND EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo) AS TotalCalls,

(SELECT COUNT(Distinct EventAgentID) FROM Events JOIN dbo.ContactType 
                    ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID
                     WHERE ContactTypeName = 'Call' AND EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo) AS UniqueCalls,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Events JOIN dbo.ContactType 
                    ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID 
                    WHERE ContactTypeName = 'Email' AND EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo) AS TotalEmails,

(SELECT COUNT(Distinct EventAgentID) FROM Events JOIN dbo.ContactType 
                    ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID 
                    WHERE ContactTypeName = 'Email' AND EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo) AS UniqueEmails,

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EventAgentID)
FROM Events 
JOIN dbo.ContactType 
ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AgentID, (SELECT CASE WHEN AgentDateOfRecentInstruction Is Null OR 
                    AgentDateOfRecentInstruction < DATEADD(month, -12, @DateFrom) --for sp change get date to @FromDate
                    THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END) AS InstructedWithinPastYear FROM Agents) ti
ON Events.EventAgentID=ti.AgentID
WHERE EventToFrom='1' 
AND (ContactTypeName = 'Email' OR ContactTypeName = 'Call')
AND InstructedWithinPastYear = 'NO'
AND (EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo)) AS AgentsContacted,

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EventAgentID)
    FROM Events 
    Join dbo.AGents
    ON EventAgentID=AgentID
    JOIN dbo.ContactType 
    ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AgentID, (SELECT CASE WHEN AgentDateOfRecentInstruction Is Null OR 
                        AgentDateOfFirstIntsruction < @DateFrom --for sp change get date to @FromDate
                        THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END) AS InstructedWithinPastYear FROM Agents) ti
    ON Events.EventAgentID=ti.AgentID
    WHERE EventToFrom='1' 
    AND (ContactTypeName = 'Email' OR ContactTypeName = 'Call')
    AND (AgentDateOfRecentInstruction <= @DateTo AND AgentDateOfRecentInstruction >= @DateFrom)
    AND (EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo)) AS Instructed    

    FROM Events
    JOIN dbo.ContactType 
    ON EventContactType=ContactTypeID
    Join dbo.AGents
    ON EventAgentID=AgentID
) 
as s

PIVOT (count(EventAgentID) FOR year
IN ([2013],[2014]) ) pvt
```

Which returns thousands of row of this:

```
TotalCalls | UniqueCalls | TotalEmails | UniqueEmails | AgentsContacted | Instructed
169        | 106     | 202         | 125          | 24              | 15
169        | 106     | 202         | 125          | 24              | 15
169        | 106     | 202         | 125          | 24              | 15
```

I want to it to return:

```
Year | TotalCalls | UniqueCalls | TotalEmails | UniqueEmails | AgentsContacted
2014 | 169        | 106         | 202         | 125      | 24
2013 | 69         | 68          | 112         | 86       | 13
```

I'm fairly certain I'm doing a few things wrong here but I wasn't able to write my question succinctly enough to work out how to do it from searches.

(note: The local variables are there temporarily whilst I write the procedure)

Comment: Look into CTEs (Common Table Expressions) to simplify this query: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably simplify this query greatly by putting everything into one query statement, rather than a series of individual queries in the SELECT statement.  Right now, you have "`SELECT (SELECT Blah1FROM X), (SELECT Blah2 FROM X)`" where you could just as easily write "`SELECT Blah1, Blah2 FROM X`" with a little creativity.

You have a couple of basic flaws in your code that are causing your problem - you're aggregating every row in each of your SELECT queries, so the data you're returning is actually the count across all records, not for the year you want.  In addition, you never group your results (look up the `GROUP BY` statement) so you're returning thousands of rows, one for each detail record, rather than the single row per year I think you want.

Consider writing something more like the following, which uses aggregations against a single query with the GROUP BY.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom Date = '01-Jan-2014', @DateTo Date = '31-Dec-2014'
SELECT 
    YEAR(EventDate) AS [Year],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ContactTypeName = 'Call' THEN EventAgentID END) AS TotalCalls, -- You might need the "EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo" as part of this CASE statement
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ContactTypeName = 'Call' THEN EventAgentID END) AS UniqueCalls, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ContactTypeName = 'Email' THEN EventAgentID END) AS TotalEmails,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ContactTypeName = 'Email' THEN EventAgentID END) AS UniqueEmails, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE 
            WHEN    
                EventToFrom='1' AND 
                ContactTypeName IN ('Call', 'Email') AND 
                (AgentDateOfRecentInstruction IS NULL OR  AgentDateOfRecentInstruction < DATEADD(month, -12, @DateFrom)) AND 
                (EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo)
            THEN EventAgentID
        END) AS AgentsContacted, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE 
            WHEN    
                EventToFrom='1' AND 
                ContactTypeName IN ('Call', 'Email') AND 
                AgentDateOfRecentInstruction <= @DateTo AND AgentDateOfRecentInstruction >= @DateFromAND 
                (EventDate >= @DateFrom AND EventDate <= @DateTo)
            THEN EventAgentID
        END) AS AgentsContacted

FROM 
    dbo.Events
     INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ContactType ON 
        EventContactType=ContactTypeID
     INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Agents ON 
        EventAgentID=AgentID
GROUP BY YEAR(EventDate)
```

Lacking any sample data or even really a schema, I can't guarantee that this conversion will work without any tweaks - you'll likely have to take this code, check for spelling or syntax errors, then go through each statement to make sure it's actually doing what you want it to.  It should, however, get you started.

Comment: Whatever the solution, is should distill down to 
SELECT Year(EventDate) AS Year, COUNT(...), COUNT(...), COUNT(...)
FROM ...
GROUP BY Year(EventDate)

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the understanding I needed in order to build the query.